# Counting number of rows grouped by date and hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

I am tracking customer store entry data in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 that looks something like this:

```
DoorID        DateTimeStamp               EntryType
1             2013-09-02 09:01:16.000     IN
1             2013-09-02 09:04:09.000     IN
1             2013-09-02 10:19:29.000     IN
1             2013-09-02 10:19:30.000     IN
1             2013-09-02 10:19:32.000     OUT
1             2013-09-02 10:26:36.000     IN
1             2013-09-02 10:26:40.000     OUT
```

I don't want to count the `OUT` rows, just `IN`.

I believe that it needs to be grouped on `Date`, and `DoorID`, then get the hours totals.

I would like it to come out like this.

```
Date        DoorID  HourOfDay TotalInPersons
2013-09-02  1       0         0
2013-09-02  1       1         0
2013-09-02  1       2         0
2013-09-02  1       3         0
2013-09-02  1       4         0
2013-09-02  1       5         0
2013-09-02  1       6         0
2013-09-02  1       7         0
2013-09-02  1       8         0
2013-09-02  1       9         2
2013-09-02  1       10        3
2013-09-02  1       11        0
2013-09-02  1       12        0
2013-09-02  1       13        0
2013-09-02  1       14        0
2013-09-02  1       15        0
2013-09-02  1       16        0
2013-09-02  1       17        0
2013-09-02  1       18        0
2013-09-02  1       19        0
2013-09-02  1       20        0
2013-09-02  1       21        0
2013-09-02  1       22        0
2013-09-02  1       23        0
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I really did not want to port 230+ records that was used to the second list, but if it helps I can. As to your second question, I thought the requested output clarified what I was needing.  I thought that door id 2 would look like door id 1. 24 row for door 1 and 24 rows for door 2.

Comment: I wasn't asking for 230+ rows. I was asking for sample output that matched the input. Shouldn't TotalInPersons for hour 9 be 2, given the sample data you've shown? Why make me try to figure out how you arrived at 5?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I changed the data and the requested output.

Comment: Thank you, that is much more logical and intuitive. While it was relatively clear what you meant, when the sample doesn't match the output, it is natural for us to question if we really understood what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, DateTimeStamp), 
  DoorID,
  HourOfDay = DATEPART(HOUR, DateTimeStamp),
  TotalInPersons = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.tablename
WHERE EntryType = 'IN'
GROUP BY 
  CONVERT(DATE, DateTimeStamp),
  DoorID,
  DATEPART(HOUR, DateTimeStamp)
ORDER BY
  [Date], DoorID, HourOfDay;
```

Of course if you need all hours, even where no rows are represented, here is one solution (which limits the output for any day only to the doors that have at least one `IN` entry on that day):

```
;WITH h AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (24) h = number FROM Master..spt_values 
  WHERE type = N'P' ORDER BY number
),
doors AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT DoorID, [Date] = CONVERT(DATE,DateTimeStamp) 
  FROM dbo.tablename WHERE EntryType = 'IN'
)
SELECT 
  d.[Date],
  d.DoorID,
  HourOfDay = h.h,
  TotalInPersons = COUNT(t.EntryType) 
FROM doors AS d CROSS JOIN h
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tablename AS t
ON CONVERT(DATE, t.DateTimeStamp) = d.[Date]
AND t.DoorID = d.DoorID
AND DATEPART(HOUR, t.DateTimeStamp) = h.h
AND t.EntryType = 'IN'
GROUP BY d.[Date], d.DoorID, h.h
ORDER BY d.[Date], d.DoorID, h.h;
```

Comment: I believe I understand all the code here in this answer, with one exception, the "Master..spt_values". I have never seen this used before.

Comment: It's just a system table. [If you have your own Numbers table, which you should, that is better](http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1).

Comment: Thanks, that explain it.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(DateTimeStamp AS DATE) AS Date
  ,DoorID        
  ,DATEPART(HOUR, DateTimeStamp) AS HourOfDay
  ,COUNT(*) AS TotalInPersons
FROM StoreTable
WHERE EntryType = 'IN'
GROUP BY
  CAST(DateTimeStamp AS DATE)
  ,DoorID        
  ,DATEPART(HOUR, DateTimeStamp)
```

Comment: That looks an awful lot like answers that have already been posted. How many duplicates do we need?

Comment: Can never have too many right answers! I need a web browser that autocratically refreshes every couple of seconds.

Comment: @DaveSexton - "autocratically", joke or typo? :)

Comment: @Jeff - Freudian slip

Comment: @DaveSexton - Too funny !!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I guessed on how you would pull DoorID and TotalPersons, but the overall logic is correct

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,dateColumn) AS Date, 
  datepart(hh,dateColumn) AS HourOfDay, 
  DoorID,
  COUNT(people) AS TotalPersons
FROM yourtable
WHERE EntryType = 'IN'
GROUP BY CONVERT(date,dateColumn), datepart(hh,dateColumn), DoorID
ORDER BY CONVERT(date,dateColumn), datepart(hh,dateColumn)
```